# Large-scale embedded software that can run on Raspberry

Tags: open-source, raspberry-pi, embedded-systems

I'm looking for a large-scale embedded software(specific usage) that can be used in my experiment, it needs to satisfy:

1) It should be large-scale or complex written in C language, I want to do some hooking job in it and test whether the hooking job would influence its runtime performance.

2) It should be open-source, for I can obtain it's source code to do the hooking job.

3) My experiment platform is Raspberry Pi 2 on top of Raspbian operating system, so the software can run on it.

4) It couldn't be better if it has limited input sets, for example like the washing machine program, which has limited possible inputs.

So anybody knows a software to meet these needs and where can I get it? I think it may be a ported software from other embedded devices.This is import and urgent for me, so if anyone knows it, please tell me about it, thank you very much!

Comment: What does "large scale" mean? You example of a washing machine is not complex, so I doubt if it means that. Just lots of code? Doe sit need to have inputs? From sensors, or could it read from a file?

Comment: @Mawg thank you for your replying, yeah, washing machine code is not complex, here I use washing machine just to explain my fourth point about limited inputs. Large scale is not so exact here, I just want to find a software can be used in my hooking job, I want to hook the branches in it. The program may have at least several thousands lines code, complex here refers more to the software with a lot of branches, including function calls or conditional branches. I think it should have inputs or read files like you say, but it should have limited control-flow paths through the whole program

Comment: @Mawg I want to the test whether my hooking job on branches will influent the performance comparing to the original program, so I just need a program with considerable branches, that's what I call complex here.